# Attribute that returns a single object from a List inside the same class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a List<> that holds the status history for the record. I'd like to include an attribute that will return the most recent status from that list.

The problem is extensions such as .OrderByDescending are not available when accessing the List from within the class.

Here is an example:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CourseStatus> CourseStatusList { get; set; }

    public CourseStatus Current
    {
        get 
        {
              //Return a single CourseStatus object from 
              //CourseStatusList with max(InsertDate)
        }
    }
}

public class CourseStatus
{
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

I normally do this in my DAL, but wondered if it was possible to have the class do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose a Property to sort by and pass it as a lambda expression to OrderByDescending

like:

```
using System.Linq;

    return CourseStatusList.OrderByDescending(s => s.InsertDate)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

refer this link also

[LInq Order By and Order By Desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305700/linq-order-by-and-order-by-desc)

Answer (score 1):

You can [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx) then get the first item:

```
return CourseStatusList.OrderByDescending(s => s.InsertDate)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: For some reason that method is not available to me: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CourseStatus>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending'...

Answer (score 1):

add reference to

```
using System.Linq;
```

then

```
var maxInsertDate =  CourseStatusList.Max(y => y.InsertDate);
return CourseStatusList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InsertDate== maxInsertDate);
```